# Does renaming a database table via a migration on Heroku get handled gracefully in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When you rename a database table via a Rails 4.2 migration that is actively in use every second (say a CarSales table for a car company), does Heroku handle that renaming gracefully - in a way that you don’t have to worry that while you’re writing to table “OldName” you’re not going to lose data while you’re renaming it to “NewName”?

Comment: This probably depends more on the database than on heroku. What database are you using? Have you checked the docs for that database?

Comment: Postgresql is the database flavor

Comment: Which version of postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [alter table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) docs for PG9.5 states that in general that

> An ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock is held unless explicitly noted.

As for `RENAME`:

> The RENAME forms change the name of a table (or an index, sequence, view, materialized view, or foreign table), the name of an individual column in a table, or the name of a constraint of the table. There is no effect on the stored data.

Which makes it sound like accessing the table will not be permitted while the table is being renamed.

The biggest potential problem to this change is the rails side: Is the table backed by a model? Will you be Adding a new model to match the new name or using `table_name` to change the expected

The combination of model changes + lock that will be required, it may be difficult to perform all of the necessary operations with 0 downtime. If that is a strict requirement the change may be more difficult.